# How to use asp.net Identity mailing feature for other functions [Error displayed]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity

I am working on a forum-based project where users can submit posts. The project is made on ASP.Net's webform using Identity.

Within the IdentityConfig.cs class the code responsible for creating the structure of the email is as follows

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            //return Task.FromResult(0);
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                sendMail(message);
            });
        }

        void sendMail(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            #region formatter
            string text = string.Format("Please click on this link to {0}: {1}", message.Subject, message.Body);
            string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + message.Body + "\">link</a><br/>";

            html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"Or click on the copy the following link on the browser:" + message.Body);
            #endregion

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString());
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            msg.Subject = message.Subject;
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
        }
```

Once a user registers this is the code that's used to submit the email is as follows

```
string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
```

I tried to recreate the following code in order to be able to send an email for other functions related to the project. I firstly tried to make a second    "void sendmail" directly under that is as follows

```
public void sendCoordinatorMail(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            #region formatter
            string text = string.Format("A user of your department has submitted a post.");
            string html = "";

            html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"" + message.Body);
            #endregion

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString());
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            msg.Subject = message.Subject;
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

The code above is needed to construct an email that is sent to the forum admin whenever a user creates and submits a post, there I added the following code after the "Post newPost = new Post()" code which is as follows

```
manager.sendCoordinatorMail(user.Id, "A user of your department has submitted a post.", "");
```

I seem to get an error on "sendCoordinatorMail" that says

```
'ApplicationUserManager' does not contain a definition for 'sendCoordinatorMail' and no accessible extension method 'sendCoordinatorMail' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationUserManager' could be found.
```

I apologize for the very long question but is there something I'm obviously doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see:

Your manager is a type of `ApplicationUserManager` and your email related methods are in the `EmailService` class. You are trying to call the `sendCoordinatorMail` method through the `ApplicationUserManager`, but I assume there is no method like that in the manager.

PS: Try to setup a function in the manager that will call the `sendCoordinatorMail`.